# UTF-8 PHP Causes 'Header Already Sent' Issue, Converting to UTF-8 Without BOM Fixes

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

In my website I have a file uploading form that takes a text file (saved as UTF-8 in notepad) and then it takes the contents of the file and puts it into a php file after some other stuff.

```
$meat = '<?php setcookie("' . $cookieTitle . '", "read",  time()+36000000, "/", ".petercort.com", 1); 
include("../header.php");?>
<div id="articleContent">
<div id="article"><p><h1>' . $title . '</h1></p>' . $content . '</div>
<div id="addComment">
    <form action="userComment.php" name="userComment" method="post">
    <textarea name="comment" id="comment" rows="15" cols="70">Add your comment here!</textarea>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="comments">
<?php include("../comments.php"); getComments(' . $postID . ');?>
</div>
<?php include("../footer.html");?>';

$dest = "news/" . $title . ".php";
$open = fopen($dest, 'a') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($open, trim($meat))
```

So this is what gets written to a new file.  The issue that I'm having is when I access the page from my site it gives me this error

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by blahblahblah on line 1
```

There's nothing before the cookie and the include so I couldn't figure out what was going on, but when I open up the file in notepad++ and look at the encoding it says Encode In UTF-8 is selected, and when I change it to Encode In UTF-8 Without BOM, and then upload that same file, it works fine.  How do I work around this, and make it so whatever is causing data to get passed before my php info stops!?

Comment: You already found the solution to this problem — don't save your UTF-8 files with BOMs. You can remove them at the server end by deleting `0xEF` `0xBB` `0xBF` from the beginning of the file, if it exists there.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what caused it to be fixed, but by changing the fopen mode from 'a' to 'w' (since I'm no longer having any pre-populated text in the file) and it appears to have fixed my issue. I'm not going to mark this as fixed just yet or answer my own question as I would like someone to perhaps give a more detailed explanation about why this is (or isn't) the fix. (I will also not be a lazy slob and do some research for myself!)

Comment: Just to add, if you are using BOM because your editor is not detecting the utf8 encoding, get a better editor ;)

Comment: @squeamishossifrage the issue with that is the pages are being dynamically created and I can't take the time to go in and manually delete parts of a file every time a file is uploaded to the server.

Comment: @Tomdarkness I was using notepad because I don't have any other text editor installed on my computer (aside from notepad++) and that's why I was curious about it.  Also using a google doc converted to a .txt file creates the same issues.